# How does Nunnaly get crippled?

Tags: code-geass

From rewatching the *Code Geass* series, I understand that Charles zi had used his geass to cause Nunnaly to believe that she was blind.

Did his geass cause her to become a cripple too? When I checked the Wikia, it was not made very clear.

Comment: I removed the question about the relation between the manga & the anime because it's not related to the current question (anyway, it's been answered [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5703/are-the-code-geass-manga-just-different-perspectives)). If there are multiple unrelated questions, please ask each in a separate post so that the community can focus and answer it better.

Answer (score 1):

No, Nunnally was injured by V.V's attack as indicated in her [Character Outline](http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Nunnally_vi_Britannia#Character_Outline)

> When her mother was assassinated, Nunnally was paralyzed by bullet wounds on her legs, and went blind due to the geass of her father making her believe that she is blind.

and infact her physical injuries were planned but not by Charles but by V.V

> When Lelouch converses with Charles and Marianne in The Ragnarök Connection (episode), it is revealed that **Nunnally's injuries were orchestrated by V.V., who set her up to be a witness to the murder of her mother.** Her blindness, which was thought to be psychological, was actually the result of Charles' Geass, done to protect her against possible reprisal by V.V. Charles then chose to send them both away, arguing that he was doing so to protect them from V.V., whom he felt he could no longer trust.

Source: [Nunnally > Character History > Season 2 (4th Paragraph)](http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Nunnally_vi_Britannia#Second_Season)

also if you look at all the Geass Abilities none of them caused any outward physical damage to their targets.

- Charles could manipulate Memories and seal Nunnally's Eyesight (by what we could suspect would be manipulating her memories thinking she was blind)
- Lelouch could control people's minds and make them obey him
- Mao could read minds
- Rolo could affect people's perception of time making them think time had frozen
- C.C could make people fall in love with her

as you can see, all of these could actually be linked to only affecting a person's mind or how they thought and ofcause with the exception of Mao's power all of these powers were temporary as such Charles's Geass couldn't have caused any permanent physical damage to any other part of the body

Answer (score 0):

That's actually not addressed by the show.
We know Lelouch's memories of her murder were fake, a result of his father's geass, and we know that V.V. orchestrated the whole thing, and we also know that her blindness was the effect of Charles' geass.
But what of her being crippled?
There are several possibilities.
Perhaps they really crippled her to make the whole thing look real (a horrifying thought!).
Or perhaps her legs were fine and Charles' geass just made her believe she was cripple, and by the time she broke his geass her legs had atrophied to the point of being useless. But in that case, why did her eyes not atrophy as well?

Alas, right now there's no real answer.
maybe the sequel will bring us the answer. Maybe not.